# AngularJS directive - ng-class in ng- repeat should it be a $watcher to toggle style?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I am currently implementing a spike to further my understanding on angular directives etc.

The premise is to create a FX watch list on a number of currency pairs.

My data feed is set up for my price updates via socket.io.

The stumbling block that i have is being able to change the css dependent on price change ie up arrow for up, down arrow for down.

I feel a watcher function is what i need but struggled on where to start so was looking for some sort of expression in ng-class to do the job ... but the method not only started to look like a $watcher it was also flawed as saving the previous price to scope on my directive meant there was only ever one old value not one for each price.

There for my question is : Is the solution with ng-class or in setting up a $watcher function ?

Heres my code ...

HTML template

```
<div ng-repeat="rate in rates" ng-click="symbolSelected(rate)">
        <div class="col-1-4">
            {{rate.symbol}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-1-4">
            <span ng-class='bullBear(rate.bidPoint)' ></span> {{rate.bidBig}}<span class="point">{{rate.bidPoint}}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1-4">
            <span ng-class='bullBear(rate.offerPoint)' ></span> {{rate.offerBig}}<span class="point">{{rate.offerPoint}}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1-4">
            {{rate.timeStamp | date : 'hh:mm:ss'}}
        </div>

    </div>
```

My directive currently looks like this ... as noted this will not work and the bullBear method was starting to look like a $watcher function.

```
.directive('fxmarketWatch', function(fxMarketWatchPriceService){

        return {

            restrict:'E',
            replace:'true',
            scope: { },

            templateUrl:'common/directives/fxMarketWatch/marketwatch.tpl.html',

            controller : function($scope, SYMBOL_SELECTED_EVT,fxMarketWatchPriceService){

                $scope.symbolSelected = function(currency){
                    $scope.$emit(SYMBOL_SELECTED_EVT,currency);
                }

                $scope.bullBear = function(newPrice){


                    if ($scope.oldPrice> newPrice ){

                           return ['glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down','priceDown'];
                     }
                     else if ($scope.oldPrice > newPrice ){

                           return ['glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up','priceUp'];
                     }

                }


                $scope.$on('socket:fxPriceUpdate', function(event, data) {

                    $scope.rates  =  data.payload;

                });
            }

        }

    })
```

Comment: AFter restructuring my data, this problem become rather simple to solve and i used a solution very much like suggested by Konstantin Krass, although in the context of my initial problem b0nyb0y solution worked and provided me with more insight into watchers so it gets my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you to use both `ng-class` and `$watcher`. The two can actually compliment each other:

**UPDATE:** To make the code works with `ng-repeat`, we need to migrate all of CSS classes logic to another `controller`:

```
app.controller('PriceController', function($scope) {
    // we first start off as neither up or down
    $scope.cssBid = 'glyphicon';
    $scope.cssOffer = 'glyphicon';

    var cssSetter = function(newVal, oldVal, varName) {
        if (angular.isDefined(oldVal) && angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
            if (oldVal > newVal) {
                $scope[varName] = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down priceDown';
            } else if (newVal > oldVal) {
                $scope[varName] = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up priceUp';
            } else {
                $scope[varName] = 'glyphicon';
            }
        }
    };

    // watch for change in 'rate.bidPoint'
    $scope.$watch('rate.bidPoint', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        cssSetter(newVal, oldVal, 'cssBid');
    });
    // watch for change in 'rate.offerPoint'
    $scope.$watch('rate.offerPoint', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        cssSetter(newVal, oldVal, 'cssOffer');
    });
});
```

Next, we bind this `PriceController` onto `ng-repeat` div. By doing so, Angular will create one `controller` instance for each `rate` in `rates`. So this time `rate.bidPoint` and `rate.offerPoint` should be available for `$watch`-ing:

```
<div ng-repeat="rate in rates" ng-click="symbolSelected(rate)" ng-controller="PriceController">
    <div class="col-1-4">
        <span ng-class='cssBid'></span> {{rate.bidBig}}<span class="point">{{rate.bidPoint}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1-4">
        <span ng-class='cssOffer'></span> {{rate.offerBig}}<span class="point">{{rate.offerPoint}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, directive's controller will be much shorter than before:

```
controller: function($scope, SYMBOL_SELECTED_EVT, fxMarketWatchPriceService){
    $scope.symbolSelected = function(currency) {
        $scope.$emit(SYMBOL_SELECTED_EVT, currency);
    }

    $scope.$on('socket:fxPriceUpdate', function(event, data) {
        $scope.rates = data.payload;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have tested your solution - although the $watch methods are not firing - only once on initiation - is it because ( and again im firing in the dark as im only just starting to get my head around $watchers ) there isnt actually a property rate.bid on the scope rate.bid would be found on $scope.rates[n]rate.bidPoint ?

Comment: @SPA Ah, right. I totally forgot that all of this is wrapped inside `ng-repeat`.  We can still use `$watch` if we introduce controller per ng-repeat instance, though. I'm away from my desk right now, but will write up another solution when i get back.

Comment: @SPA With this updated solution, `$watch` should now work, and each `rate` can have its CSS strings updated independently from one another.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the `ng-class` and move the logic into the view, because styling and placing classes shouldn't be done in code.

```
<div class="col-1-4">
  <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-arrow-up priceUp': oldPrice > rate.bidPoint, 'glyphicon-arrow-down priceDown':oldPrice > rate.bidPoint}"></span> {{rate.bidBig}}<span class="point">{{rate.bidPoint}}</span>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon {{oldPrice > rate.bidPoint ? 'glyphicon-arrow-down priceDown':'glyphicon-arrow-up priceUp'}}></span> {{rate.bidBig}}<span class="point">{{rate.bidPoint}}</span>
```

Comment: Ok cool , but where would you get the old price from ? - i appreciate that i have $scope.oldPrice in the directive but this is a little mis leading as i stopped going down this path when as mentioned i relised the approach was flawed as oldPrice is getting set on every call to that method.